# I am trying to implement an AJAX call. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

This is my HTML text:

```
<input type="text" class="resizedsearch" name="searchdb">
<button id="submit" onclick="ajaxCall()">Search!</button>
```

This is Javascript:

```
ajaxCall()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "http://localhost:8080/CSE%205335%20Project%20One/userInfo.php";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()

    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
        {
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send('searchdb');

    function myFunction(response)
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);

        document.getElementById("democity").innerHTML =
        obj.city;

        document.getElementById("demodes").innerHTML =
        obj.description;

        document.getElementById("latlon").innerHTML =
        obj.latitude + "," + obj.longitude;

    }
}
```

And this is where I am trying to display the response that I am receiving from the PHP file:

```
<b><font size="24" face="Cambria"><p id="democity"></p></font></b>
<font size="6" face="Cambria"><p id="demodes"></p></font>
</br>
```

The output of the PHP file is stored in $outp and it is in the JSON format.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

!!UPDATE!!

```
function ajaxCall()
{
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:8080/CSE%205335%20Project%20One/userInfo.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
{

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send('searchdb');

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
    {
    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
}

function myFunction(response)
{
var obj = JSON.parse(response);

document.getElementById("democity").innerHTML =
obj.city;

document.getElementById("demodes").innerHTML =
obj.description;

document.getElementById("latlon").innerHTML =
obj.latitude + "," + obj.longitude;

}
```

This is how the improvised code looks. Still not working.

Comment: You need to learn how to look in the console to see what script errors you have.  This is a very basic debugging step that is necessary for learning how to solve your own problems.  You should see at least one error there already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example by FactoryAidan is not going to work as it violates Same Origin Policy (unless you'll run the code in browser console on Google page). Try replacing `http://www.google.com` with your local address. I tested the code with a little modification and it works, or at least gives alert, so the function is called. Here's it is:

```
function ajaxCall(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080"; /* but make sure the url is accessible and of same origin */

    xmlhttp.onload=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send('searchdb');
}


function myFunction(response){
    alert('I made it here');
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. :) If my answer solved your issue, I'd be happy if you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code update after my first answer looks like it was done in haste and I think makes the question a little harder.  The .open() and .send() methods ended up inside your .onreadystatechange function definition but they need to be outside.  Your first one didn't have those placement issues. The code I wrote below has your exact building blocks but with no placement issues so you should be able to follow along with how it matches your example code.  I also tested it and it sucessfully sends and receives data back and successfully calls the myFunction() callback function.

Nonetheless, I took your code and rewrote it a bit.  If you get an alert('') message when you run it, that means that your xml request worked perfectly.  If you don't see an alert('') message. It means your xml request is returning a http 404 error, which means your request URL is bad. Try changing your request URL to something you know won't give you a 404 error, like 'http://www.google.com'.  If it works and you get the alert message, then the only problem is that your localhost:8080 url is a bad url.

Also, in your myFunction callback function, javascript treats line-breaks as the end of a line of code.  So you must write assignments that use an '=' sign on the same line with no line-breaks. Due to this javascrit principle, you also don't need a semicolon ';' at the end of a single line like you would in PHP script.

Finally, a big cause of errors can be the JSON.parse() call.  The data received MUST be a valid json string.  So if the URL you call returns anything other than pure json... your myFunction() callback function will break on the JSON.parse() command.

Lastly, if there is an error in your myFunction() callback function, your browser inspector will not report it in a useful way and will instead throw an error that points to your xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){} as being the culprit because that is where the browser thinks the error resides (being the calling function), even though the real error is in your myFunction() callback function.  Using my edit of your ajaxCall(){...} code  and with a valid url, you can be positive that the ajax call works and any errors you have are in your myFunction() callback function.

Lastly again, You have to be careful in your callback function because there are so many things that could break it.  For example, document.getElementById() will cause an error if no html element exists on your web-page with the id you provided.  Also, if the JSON you received back from the ajax call is missing any properties you mentioned like (city or latitude) it is likely that the innerHTML will be set to 'undefined'.  But some browsers may treat the missing json properties as an error instead of just saying they are 'undefined' when you try to call them.

```
function ajaxCall(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://www.google.com";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send('searchdb');
}


function myFunction(response){
    alert('I made it here')
/*
    var obj = JSON.parse(response);

    document.getElementById("democity").innerHTML = obj.city

    document.getElementById("demodes").innerHTML = obj.description

    document.getElementById("latlon").innerHTML = obj.latitude + "," + obj.longitude
*/
}
```

Comment: I added that. Still not difference. Anything else?